# jQuery is not rendering properly datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

i am Django user i want to render out my api data using jQuery. Api data is rendered but the datatable is not working properly. but when i render data in datatable using django template datatable working fine. i thing some class's of datatable maybe not working. i try harder but i don't know how can i debug this thing. can anybody know how can i render datatable properly in html using jQuery?

[it's jQuery Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlJEi.png)

[Django Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMAdJ.png)

```
<table id="approvedData">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Story</th>
            <th>Created By</th>
            <th>Timestamp</th>
            <th>Priority</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="approvedList">

    </tbody>
</table>
```

index.js

```
function fetchData() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: endpoint,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
            var html = '';
            data.map(object => {
                let storyStatus = ('Story not finish');
                let colorClassName = ("badge-danger");

                if (object.story_status === "sf") {
                    colorClassName = "badge-success";
                    storyStatus = "Story finish"
                }

                if (object.story_status === "fr") {
                    colorClassName = "badge-success";
                    storyStatus = "Approved"
                }
                html += `<tr>
                            <td> ` + object.id + `</td>           
                            <td><a href="#"> ` + object.title + `</a></td>          
                            <td> ` + object.author + `</td>           
                            <td> ` + moment(object.created_on).fromNow() + `</td>           
                            <td><span class="badge ${colorClassName} id="story-status">${storyStatus}</span></td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="table-btns">
                                    <a href="${updateURL}update/${object.id}" class="table-btn table-btn--edit">
                                        <i class="icon ion-ios-create"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="#" class="table-btn table-btn--delete">
                                        <i class="icon ion-ios-trash"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </td>           
                        </tr>`;
                //This is selector of my <tbody> in my table
                $("#approvedList").html(html);
                $('.table-btn--delete').click(function () {
                    var this_html = $(this);
                    var pk = this_html.parent().parent().parent().children().first().text();
                    swal({
                        title: "Are you sure?",
                        text: "You will not be able to recover this story!",
                        icon: "warning",
                        buttons: true,
                        dangerMode: true,
                    })
                        .then((willDelete) => {
                            if (willDelete) {
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: '{% url "del" %}',
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    headers: { "X-CSRFToken": '{{csrf_token}}' },
                                    data: { pk: pk },
                                    success: function () {
                                        swal("Story has been deleted!", {
                                            icon: "success",
                                        });
                                        this_html.parent().parent().parent().remove();
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                swal("Story is safe");
                            }
                        });
                });
            });
        }
    });
};
fetchData();
setInterval(fetchData, 2000)
```

Comment: That looks more like a layout issue in HTML/CSS than anything to do with JS or Django. To find the differences use the DOM inspector in both versions and check for extra/missing classes or ids which affect the styling on the table or its cells

Comment: yeah cells are affected. i also debug it but didn't find anything difference between both tables?

Answer (score 1):

After modifing the rows from a rendered Datatable, You have to destroy it and rebuild the table. I'd store the table instance given by jQuery to do that.

`var myTable = $("#approvedData").DataTable();`

After inserting new rows

`myTable.destroy();`

And

```
myTable = $("#approvedData").DataTable();
```

Make sure you have 'myTable' available in the function scope

[DataTable Destroy](https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy())

Comment: i don't understand how can i destroy datatable would you like to update your code in  my Question ?